# Typescript: Object is possibly 'undefined' for an object with different types of children

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I have an object that can have 2 types of children

```
type data = {
  name: Names[];
}
type Names = {
    name?: string;
    names?: string[];
};
```

I am writing an adapter to configure the response data according to schema

```
const name = data[dataLength - 1].hasOwnProperty('name') ? data[dataLength - 1].name : data[dataLength - 1].names[0]
```

`data[dataLength - 1].names[0]` is the place where I am getting  `Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: `data[index].names` is `names?: string[]`, i.e. an _optional_ property, so may indeed be undefined. You have two separate optional properties, there's no guarantee of one _or the other_. Probably you want a type more like `{ name: string } | { names: string[] }`.

Comment: If I read this correctly,`data.name` is an array of `Names` objects, each of which can itself be an array of names, which seems an odd structure (a 2D array of names).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are 100% sure that `names` will not be undefined in this point of the code, you could use the following syntax to let Typescript know you are sure that `names` is not `undefined`

```
const name = data[dataLength - 1].hasOwnProperty('name') ? data[dataLength - 1].name : data[dataLength - 1].names![0]
```

Notice the `!` at the very end.

USE WITH CARE!
Otherwise expand your code to do more checks to let the compiler narrow down the type better or rewrite some types to have less optional properties.